# how can i update my listview items whenever i update my list of object in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

Method for sending data to the web service

```
async void getData(string center)
{
    string url = "http://10.91.91.50:7500/NNRAService/webresources/NNRA/getMedicalFilter?centerName="+center;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    //var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
    //tbOutputText.Text = data.centerName.ToString();
    //tbOutputText.Text= data.ToString();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JsonArray root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetArray();
    verifyList.Clear();
    for (uint i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
    {
        string CenterName = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("centerName");
        string Address = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("address");
        string status = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedNumber("isActive").ToString();
        if(status=="1")
        {
            active = "SAFE";
        }

        var verified = new Class4
        {
            centerName = CenterName,
            address = Address,
            isActive = active,

        };
        verifyList.Add(verified);
    };

    verifyListView.ItemsSource = verifyList;
}
```

When I call the method, I want it to work in such a way that when I change the text in the textbox and I click the button, it should generate another list for me on the list view

```
private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    vtext = vCenter.Text;
    if(vtext != null)
    {
        getData(vtext);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the `List` to save the `Class4` Collections? If so, please set the `null` to `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` before you set the `List` to the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`.

I suggest you use the `ObservableCollection`. It represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

For example:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Class4> Items;
 public MainPage()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Items = new ObservableCollection<Class4>();
     verifyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
 }
```

By the way, if we have set the `ObservableCollection` to the 
 `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` once, we do not need to set it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. Can you help me on how I can format the font size of my webview in UWP

Comment: @OlayemiRondo The question has been closed, we also need to get the HTML code and set the font size. We can not set the font size by `WebView`.

Comment: I'm getting the webview content from the API, and it is too small for presentation

Comment: @You should be able to get the HTML code and get the css code, then you can change the CSS code to change the font size.

Comment: The ObservableCollection works for me. Thanks. Please help me check my latest trend concerning AutoSuggestBox